Need to convert Object[] to date type Error: "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.DateTime"

I have a script where I need to retrieve a date string from a CSV column to compare it with a file date value (LastWriteTime).
When I run the script, I get the error outlined in the title of this post.
This the portion of the script where I create the CSV file and update the columns with the values and try to compare date value FROM CSV FILE with system date value.
I tried to convert the Import-Csv output stored in the variable to a date value but that throw an error, obviously because the variable is array object and not a string.
$lastexecutedRuntime.GetType()
[DateTime]::ParseExact($lastexecutedRuntime, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss' $null)

Output:
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                              
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

"Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.""

I appreciate your help. This is the script generating the error:
ERROR:
Could not compare "05/02/2024 09:47:26" to "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData". Error: "Cannot convert 
the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.DateTime"."
At line:124 char:8
+     If($_.LastWriteTime -le $lastexecutedRuntime){
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComparisonFailure

This is the script I tried:
#CREATE CSV FILE
$csvfilePath = DIR\Mcsvfile.csv
New-Item -Path $csvfilePath
#CREATE CSV FILE COLUMNS
Add-Content -Path $csvfilePath -Value "StartTime, EndTime, Message"

$startTime = Get-Date (Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

#FOR TESTING PURPOSES
$endTime = Get-Date (Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

#LOG TIMESTAMP IN THE CSV FILE
Add-Content -Path $csvfilePath -Value "$startTime, $endTime, Script completed"

#SORTING THE CULUMN BY DATE IN DESCENDING ORDER AND GETTING THE RECENT DATE VALUE
$lastexecutedRuntime = Import-Csv -Path $csvfilePath | Sort-Object -Property EndTime -Descending | where-Object { $_."EndTime" -as [DateTime]} | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders EndTime | Select-Object -First 3

Get-ChildItem $backupDir| ForEach-Object {

    If($_.LastWriteTime -le $lastexecutedRuntime){
         # CODE HERE   
    }else{
         # CODE HERE
    }
}


I apologize for the formatting as this was my first post in Stack overflow, and I will keep your formatting suggestions in mind for my futures posts.
Based on the script and  the import-Csv command I am using, what is the cleanest way to retrieve the last date entry in the csv file after I sort the output? That is where I am struggling.  Thank you for your help.
Import-Csv -Path $myfile | Sort-Object -Property EndTime -Descending | where-Object { $_."EndTime" -as [DateTime]}



Your $lastexecutedRuntime variable contains an array of values, due to Select-Object -First 3, which is the immediate cause of the problem: you cannot compare a single [datetime] LHS value to an RHS array of values (whatever its elements' types are),[1] and that is what the error message is trying to tell you in response to
$_.LastWriteTime -le $lastexecutedRuntime

The follow-up problem is that you're mistakenly processing the output from a Format-* cmdlet (... | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders EndTime | Select-Object -First 3), which is to be avoided: Such cmdlets emit output objects whose sole purpose is to provide formatting instructions to PowerShell's for-display output-formatting system. In short: only ever use Format-* cmdlets to format data for display, never for subsequent programmatic processing. See this answer for more information.


In a comment you ask:

Based on the script and the Import-Csv command I am using, what is the cleanest way to retrieve the last date entry in the csv file after I sort the output?

$lastexecutedRuntime = 
  (
    Import-Csv -Path $csvfilePath | 
      ForEach-Object { if ($dt = $_.EndTime -as [datetime]) { $dt } } |
      Sort-Object -Descending
  )[0]

This will obtain the most recent date (timestamp) stored in the CSV's EndTime column as a [datetime] instance.
Note that the assumption is that the date strings stored in the CSV are directly recognized as [datetime] instances; if that isn't true, use a [datetime]::ParseExact() call describing the format.

If you're sure that all date strings in the EndTime column are directly recognized as [datetime] instances (which notably means there mustn't be empty fields), you can make the command more efficient with an array cast ([datetime[]]):
$lastexecutedRuntime = 
  (
    [datetime[]] (Import-Csv -Path $csvfilePath).EndTime | 
      Sort-Object -Descending
  )[0]

Note the use of member-access enumeration to extract all EndTime values, from all objects returned by the Import-Csv call.

[1] While -eq and -ne - as opposed to less-than/greater-than comparisons and their variants (-lt, -le, -gt, -ge) - do not cause an error, they also don't work meaningfully in this case. Note that the behavior of PowerShell's comparison operators changes fundamentally if you put an array (enumerable) on the LHS (and a scalar on the RHS): they then act as filters, returning the sub-array of matching items - see the docs.

Thank you "mklement0",The Code with the ForEach-Object command worked like  a charm

Thank you @mklement0,
The Code with the ForEach-Object command worked great. Exactly what I needed. I modified the import-Csv command slightly using the same concept you shared. This is the modified code:
$lastexecutedRuntime = ((Import-Csv -Path $csvfilePath).EndTime | where-Object { $_.'EndTime' -as [datetime]; $_ } | Sort-Object -Descending)[0] $LastexecRunTime.GetType() $LastexecRunTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($lastexecutedRuntime, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture) $lastexecutedRuntime

Commands Output
`IsPublic IsSerial Name

True     True     DateTime
07/12/2024 09:33:51`

Glad to hear it helped, @MounirFarid. Please note that you can help future readers by clearly signaling which answer, if any, solved your problem, namely by accepting it.

@MounirFarid, as for your modified solution: the ; $_ part alone makes your Where-Object call in effect equivalent to Where-Object { $true }, i.e. you're not filtering at all. Also, it's better to convert the values to dates first before sorting, as the date strings  won't be sorted correctly across year boundaries. If $someDateString-as [datetime] works, so will [datetime] $someDateString, so there's no need to call datetime]::ParseExact()
